# Updating ViewModel Data?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a UserViewModel that is responsible to fetch the user information and then I display it in the UI.

**UserViewModel.java**

```
public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<UserResponse> userInfoMutableLiveData;

public MutableLiveData<UserResponse> getUserInfoMutableLiveData() {
        if (userInfoMutableLiveData == null) {
            userInfoMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
            fetchUserInfo();
        }
        return userInfoMutableLiveData;
    }

    private void fetchUserInfo() {
        // Asynchronous call using RxJava to fetch user information.
}
```

I call it in the UI in the following way.

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(UserViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getUserInfoMutableLiveData().observe(this, this::consumeResponse);   

    return view;
}
```

This displays the data correctly and it works fine.

**PROBLEM**

When there is no internet connection, my app displays a screen with a no internet connection warning and then a button to retry the call.

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onRetryClick() {
    viewModel.getUserInfoMutableLiveData().observe(this, this::consumeResponse);
}
```

Suppose the following scenario, I make the call without an internet connection --> retry button is displayed --> I reconnect to the internet and then --> press retry button.

It will keep giving me the error of no internet connection because it is just retrieving the previous `userInfoMutableLiveData` and it is not loading a new one.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried to fetch the user information in the UI like this.

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(UserViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getUserInfoMutableLiveData().observe(this, this::consumeResponse);   
    viewModel.fetchUserInfo();

    return view;
}
```

and then call `onRetryClick()` like this.

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onRetryClick() {
    viewModel.fetchUserInfo();
}
```

It solves this problem because it will make a call each time I click the retry button, however, it lost the purpose of ViewModel that is to load the data once and then retrieve it.

**What I need?**

In conclusion, I need to correctly retry the ViewModel call in case there is no internet connection.

Comment: Assuming `private void fetchUserInfo()` is populating the `userInfoMutableLiveData` you don't need to re-observe and yes calling `viewModel.fetchUserInfo();` will notify the observers with the new data! Also if you are using the latest `lifecycle_version` then you can also replace `.observe(this, this::consumeResponse)` with `.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), this::consumeResponse)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
@Override
public void onRetryClick() {
    viewModel.getUserInfoMutableLiveData().observe(this, this::consumeResponse);
}
```

You shouldn't be re-observing the livedata, you should re-issue the request using `viewModel.fetchUserInfo();`.

You don't need to re-observe it, because it's already being observed, and you don't need to call `viewModel.fetchUserInfo();` in the `onCreateView`, because it'll fetch automatically the first time you call `getUserInfoMutableLiveData`

Answer (score 0):

As the answers and comments helped me, the solution was to combine both things I was doing.

The UserViewModel should keep the same, except, `fetchUserInfo()` must be public.

**UserViewModel.java**

```
public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<UserResponse> userInfoMutableLiveData;

public MutableLiveData<UserResponse> getUserInfoMutableLiveData() {
        if (userInfoMutableLiveData == null) {
            userInfoMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
            fetchUserInfo();
        }
        return userInfoMutableLiveData;
    }

    public void fetchUserInfo() {
        // Asynchronous call using RxJava to fetch user information.
}
```

You should observe the LiveData in `onCreate()` and then recall it when retrying to load the content or updating it.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(UserViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getUserInfoMutableLiveData().observe(this, this::consumeResponse);   

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onRetryClick() {
    viewModel.fetchUserInfo();
}
```